# regarding the changes done in code to achieve the excel outcome

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am stuck up in a issue of excel generation through poi that is i want to achieve as shown in picture that is on row 6 the header should be AAA , row 7 should be blank
and on row 8 there should be another header BBB and from rest row 9 existing 
data should continue so only adjustments need to be made

I am using the below code

```
HSSFRow abcrow = worksheet.createRow((short) rowNumber++);
        HSSFCell ghjCell = abc.createCell((short)0);
        ghj.setCellStyle(cellStyleReportName);
        ghj.setCellValue("AAA");

        rowNumber++;

        HSSFRow abcdRow = worksheet.createRow((short) rowNumber++);
        HSSFCell ghjj = abcdRow.createCell((short)0);
        ghjj.setCellStyle(cellStyle00);
```

please advise how can I achieve like

```
6th row   --->AAA
7th row   --->should be blank
8th row    ---->BBB
9th row       ---> noral exisiting data
```

, what changes need to be done in code please advise

Answer (score 1):

If I am clearly understanding you problem, then it can be solved easily. Just use the following:-

```
    workSheet1.createRow(6).createCell(0).setCellValue("AAA");
    workSheet1.createRow(8).createCell(0).setCellValue("BBB");
    workSheet1.createRow(9).createCell(0).setCellValue("Do Whatever U Want Now");
```

This will create two rows of 6 and 8 row number with keeping 7 as null. Now you can do whatever you want. However as per my suggestion, please initialize 7th row and keep it blank, instead of keeping it null.

Please let me know it is not satisfying your requirement.